# Objective-C - What does a colon before a variable name in a method declaration do?

Tags: objective-c

Ran into the piece of code below:

```
int amountWritten = [aPort writePort:commandsToSend :totalAmountWritten :remaining];
```

totalAmountWritten and remaining are both int variables, what does the colon before their names mean?

Comment: The method declaration of `writePort:::` clearly is not complying with the best practices here as people usually name their parameters in the declaration. See @michael-dauterman's explanation for more.

Comment: See my discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch03.html#_sending_a_message

Comment: Thank you for the link. Nice book!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon says it's another parameter being passed

And Objective-C best practice would be to put some name or description before those colons.

Like, if I modified your method declaration a little bit:

```
- (int) writePort:(NSString *)commandsToSend 
           length:(NSInteger)lengthOfCommands 
            error:(NSError **)error;
```

Comment: Best practice would be to name these parameters as you suggest. But even Apple does this from time to time. For example, [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints::::]

Comment: Oh... That's very weird. Why would anyone do that?

Comment: Looking at the [CAMediaTimingFunction documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CAMediaTimingFunction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CAMediaTimingFunction/functionWithControlPoints::::), ugh.  All I can think is they had a summer intern write that, because if I were a dev or API manager within Apple I'd never allow that.

Comment: It never even crossed my mind, I thought they might be some C kind notation and they were combing them somehow. I'll accept the answer. Thank you.